# Google API Unable to Exchange Authorization Code for Access & Refresh Token

Tags: ios, google-api, google-plus, google-api-nodejs-client

I am adding Google+ sign in to my mobile apps. I created a new Client ID (https://console.developers.google.com) for my iOS app[image: Client ID for iOS App]

According to the docs (https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in#enable_server-side_api_access_for_your_app)

> "To obtain an access token and refresh token for your server, you can request a one-time authorization code that your server exchanges for these two tokens."

```
#pragma mark - GPPSignInDelegate Methods

- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error: (NSError *) error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {
        NSString *serverCode = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].homeServerAuthorizationCode;

        if (serverCode) {
            [[AFHTTPSessionManager manager] POST:@"http://localhost:3000/user/connect/google"
                                      parameters:@{@"device": [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString],
                                                   @"account": @"google",
                                                   @"info": serverCode}
                                         success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                                             NSLog(@"Google+ Reponse: %@", responseObject);
                                         } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                                             NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                         }];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Nodejs and Google API Node client (https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) on the server side.

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);
var scopes = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me' ];

oauth2Client.getToken('the token from ios', function(err, tokens) { 
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    } else { 
        console.log(tokens); 
        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens); 
    } 
});
```

**I get a response of "invalid_grant"**

is the client id on the server the same on the client id on the app?

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: are you trying on new googleplus sdk?

Comment: yup. using the latest npm googleapis

Comment: In your Node.js code, where is the "authorization code"?

Answer (score 0):

Once I have the authorization code, this works for me to exchange it:

```
// See https://github.com/request/request
var request = require('request');

/* For documentation on HTTP/REST means of doing this authorization code exchange, see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer
    POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.googleapis.com
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
    client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
    client_secret={client_secret}&
    redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
    grant_type=authorization_code

Here's an example of what I get back:

{
 "access_token":<snip>,
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "refresh_token": <snip>,
 "id_token": <snip>
}
*/
// The callback has two parameters: error, and the if error is null, an instance of the above json structure.
function exchangeAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode, clientId, clientSecret, callback) {
    var args = 
        {url:'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token', 
         form: {code: authorizationCode,
                client_id: clientId,
                client_secret: clientSecret,
                grant_type: "authorization_code"
               }
        }

    request.post(args, function(error, httpResponse, body) { 
        if (!error && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(null, JSON.parse(body));
        } else {
            callback(error, null);
        }
    });
}
```